# How can I port openssl_seal from PHP to NodeJS 18?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, openssl

I would like to port the `openssl_seal()` function from PHP to NodeJs.

The following code from my PHP SDK work perfectly, and this is the one I would like to port:

```php
$ivLength = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC') ?: 16;

$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLength);

openssl_seal(
    data: json_encode($data),
    sealed_data: $sealed,
    encrypted_keys: $encryptedKeys,
    public_key: [openssl_get_publickey("my-public-key")],
    cipher_algo: 'AES-256-CBC',
    iv: $iv
);

return [
    'context' => base64_encode($sealed),
    'envelope' => base64_encode($encryptedKeys[0]),
    'vector' => base64_encode($iv),
];
```

I'm using `openssl_seal()` because `openssl_public_encrypt()` has size limitations, and I do not wish to change my backend.

And I can use `openssl_open()` on the other side without any problem:

```php
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private("my-private-key");

openssl_open(
    data: base64_decode($data['context']),
    output: $context,
    encrypted_key: base64_decode($data['envelope']),
    private_key: $privateKey,
    cipher_algo: 'AES-256-CBC',
    iv: base64_decode($data['vector'])
);
```

Currently the closest thing I managed to craft is this:

```js
const algorithm = "aes-256-cbc";
const publicKey = loadPublicKey();

const key = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(32), "binary");
const ivLength = crypto.randomBytes(16).length;
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(ivLength);

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

let sealedData = cipher.update(data, "utf8", "binary");
sealedData += cipher.final("binary");

const encryptedKeys = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, iv);

return {
  context: Buffer.from(sealedData).toString("base64"),
  envelope: encryptedKeys.toString("base64"),
  vector: iv.toString("base64"),
};
```

The output format is okay, but the `openssl_open()` function always return `null`.

I checked multiple times, I'm using the right private and public keys.

Also i tried a few variants from other questions, even ChatGPT's one.

Comment: IIRC OpenSSL uses PKCS5 padding by default. Is the JS crypto lib also using PKCS5?

Comment: Also, `openssl_error_string()` might give you something useful about why it didn't decode. _Might_.

Comment: About the PKCS5, I don't know how can I check or where to find an answer.
`openssl_error_string()` gave me the following line: `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

Answer (score 1):

After an another day of debugging and searching I finally found working code:

```js
const key = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(32), "binary");
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("AES-256-CBC", key, iv);

const context = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);

const encryptedKey = crypto.publicEncrypt(
  {
    key: loadPublicKey(),
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
  },
  key,
);

return {
  context: context.toString("base64"),
  envelope: encryptedKey.toString("base64"),
  vector: iv.toString("base64"),
};
```

The most important change is the object in the `publicEncrypt` function.

I'm not exactly sure what is the default padding, but it needs to be provided, otherwise the following error will thrown by `openssl_open()`: `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

Comment: Ok I was half-right. Padding was the issue, but PKCS5 is for block ciphers and PKCS1 is for asymmetric crypto. I'm glad you found the correct setting, and I hope I didn't send you too far down the wrong rabbithole.